# Circle $x^2 + y^2 = n!$ doesn't hit any lattice points for any $n$ except for $0$, $1$, $2$ and $6$ or does it?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

I stumbled across the following problem in high school:$$
x^2 + y^2 = n!
$$
I tested it within my laptop capabilities, watched a 3b1b video [Pi in prime regularities](https://youtu.be/NaL_Cb42WyY), where he explains how to find the number of integer solutions based on prime factors. There doesn't seem to be any above $30!$. Maybe I'm wrong and there are infinitely many exceptions like $2$ and $6$, maybe the proof is too difficult for me to grasp or... I hope I'm just too blind to see the obvious.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MO. What is your question?

Comment: Hi. The question is: are there any integers above 6 for which this equation has integer pairs (x,y) as solutions.

Comment: At least for sufficiently large $n$, there will be a prime $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ such that $p \le n < 2p$. Then $p$ divides $n!$ exactly once, hence $n!$ cannot be a sum of two squares.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For $n\geq 7$, [Erdős proved](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1935-10.pdf) in 1932 that there is a prime $n/2<p\leq  n$ of the form $p=4k+3$. From this he deduces (in the same paper) that $1!$, $2!$, $6!$ are the only factorials which can be written as a sum of two squares.